# How do I solve $dx = (2+t)e^t dt$ with $t=dy/dx$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I wanted to solve $dx = (2+t)e^t dt$, where $t=dy/dx$. I can get $x = e^{dy/dx}(1+dy/dx)+c$ from it but then I'm not sure how to find $y(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
x=e^{y'}(1+y')+c_1
$$
Solving for $y'$ gives
$$
y' =-1+W(e (x-c_1))
$$
Where $W$ is Product log (or LambertW).

Integrating both sides gives
\begin{align*}
y &=-x+\frac{(x-c_1) \left(W(e (x-c_1)){}^2-W(e (x-c_1))+1\right)}{W(e (x-c_1))} + c_2
\end{align*}

Comment: I wish there was an elementary answer. Thank you answering though.

Answer (score 0):

$$
dx＝(2＋t)e^t\;dt\iff\;\left({2＋\frac {dy}{dx}}\right)\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}e^{\frac {dy}{dx}}＝1\\~\\\implies\;\int\left({2＋\frac {dy}{dx}}\right)\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}e^{\frac {dy}{dx}}\;dx＝\int\;1\;dx\\~\\e^{\frac {dy}{dx}}\left({2＋\frac {dy}{dx}}\right)-\int\frac {d^2y}{dx^2}e^{\frac {dy}{dx}}\;dx＝x＋C\\~\\e^{\frac {dy}{dx}}\left({1＋\frac {dy}{dx}}\right)＝x＋C\implies\;e^{\left({1＋\frac {dy}{dx}}\right)}\left({1＋\frac {dy}{dx}}\right)＝e(x＋C)\\~\\1＋\frac {dy}{dx}＝W\left({ex＋eC}\right)\\~\\y(x)＝－x＋\int\;W(ex＋eC)\;dx
$$